# asp.net C# Fileupload always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value, file-upload

I am working with a fileuploader to upload a picture.  However, evertyime i select the file and click the upload button it says that the fileuploader.file returns a value of false and does not run the next lines of code.  All i can find is that it has to be in in a seperate form and that the method has to be "post", but that did not fix the problem.

here is my codebehind.

```
 if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

here is my front end code.

```
                    <form id="form2" action="CompProfile.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
                    </form>
```

Comment: shouldn't your webform be runat="server"? And why is the action there, shouldn't it post back to the same page?

Comment: shouldn't the form have a `runat="server"` attribute? Is this an asp.net mvc project?

Comment: It is the 2nd form on the page and i will get an error stating cant have two runat server tags on the same page.  Also a suggestion was to use the action on a forum i found.

Comment: why do you want to have 2 forms?

Comment: I personally didn't want to run two forms, it was suggested when i google searched for a way to work around this problem.  I take it out and i still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing with a 0 byte sized file it will return false. Make sure the file actually isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should have `runat="server"` instead of `method="post"` and `action="..."`